# Cheese do not start due "GStreamer elements are missing: cluttervideosink"

Tags: gstreamer, cheese

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, and when I tried to use cheese, it showed the message `One or more needed GStreamer elements are missing: cluttervideosink` Cheese worked just fine in 13.10 and on the live CD of 14.04. I have tried installing other GStreamer things, but nothing has worked.

Comment: maybe you need to remove and install again the cheese on Ubuntu Software Center , because thats works to me.

Comment: @LawNewbie I did try that, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must indeed install gstreamer1.0-clutter

And also do `rm -r ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0` to erase gstreamer-1.0 folder inside of your /home/.cache hidden folder.

Comment: man you saved me as well. I had a similar problem : there weren't any gstreamer core elements present in my install. Did your thing, worked perfectly :)

Comment: Already had gstreamer1.0-clutter installed. This fixed mine too. Thanks!

Comment: works for me in CentOS 8